# Drools/jBPM - remote execution of rules on Kie execution server

Tags: jbpm, kie

We are currently deploying our jBPM (7.37.Final) rules to a Kie execution server and invoking rules using REST APIs automatically exposed by the execution server.

But due to some architectural limitations, we cannot invoke the rules using REST APIs. The option is do a jar (kie server client or something) based integration and invoke the rules remotely on the execution server from the client (java application).

Please advice if this is possible and if yes, how?

NOTE: Execution of rules in embed mode (adding the whole rules jar as a dependency) in the client java application is also not an option.

Regards
Vinay

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to trigger the business rules using any custom transport by providing a new capability.

I recently wrote [a post](https://sgitario.github.io/jbpm-kie-server-new-capability/) about this that uses the Apache Mina transport.

For example, this is our rule:

```
import org.jbpm.test.Person;

rule SayHello
  when
      $p : Person(age >= 21)
  then
      System.out.println("Hello " + $p.getName());
end
```

We can invoke this rule by opening a telnet session:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 9123
```

And then typing:

```
sayHello|{"lookup":"ksession","commands":[{"insert":{"object":{"org.jbpm.test.Person":{"name":"john","age":20}}}},{"fire-all-rules":""}]}
```

Where "sayHello" is the container name. In the server logs, we should see:

```
14:12:49,715 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Hello john
```

In the post, I'm adding a custom image of the kie execution server, but you can achieve the same just by copying the custom capability jar into the kie execution server folder WEB-INF/lib/.